# Poincaré–Miranda \ Intermediate Value theorem for mappings from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, roots

currently, I am looking for the existence of zeros of a vector valued function $\vec{f}(\vec{x}): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$. For my specific problem, $n=2$ and $m=6$ (The dimensions could change as I make changes to function $f$). I know that I can expect a continuity of the function, but not continuous derivability due to the underlying physics.

I saw that there is a theorem called Poincaré–Miranda or Intermediate Value Theorem, which basically tells me that If I have $\vec{f}(\vec{x}_1) \leq \vec{0} \leq \vec{f}(\vec{x}_2)$ that there is a $\vec{f}(\vec{x_3}) = \vec{0}$. From the [related Wikpedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Miranda_theorem) it seems that this only holds for projections to the same dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

**Question 1**

Is there an extension of Poincaré–Miranda Theorem to functions $\vec{f}(\vec{x}): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$?

**Question 2**

What if I artificially make my projection fulfill the requirements for the Poincaré–Miranda Theorem?

E.g.:
I have a function $\vec{f}(\vec{x}): (x_1,x_2,x_3) \rightarrow (f_1(\vec{x}), f_2(\vec{x}))$. I know that both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are smooth. Then $f_3(\vec{x}) = f_1(\vec{x})+f_2(\vec{x})$ is also smooth. Also for $f_1(\vec{x_a}) \geq 0$ and $f_2(\vec{x_a}) \geq 0$ it follows that  $f_3(\vec{x_a}) \geq 0$ and vice versa for $f_1(\vec{x_b}) \leq 0$ and $f_2(\vec{x_b}) \leq 0$. Hence, the theorem should be applicable to the new function $\vec{f_{new}}(\vec{x}): (x_1,x_2,x_3) \rightarrow (f_1(\vec{x}), f_2(\vec{x}), f_3(\vec{x}))$. Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks :)

Comment: This is false even if you require the function to be smooth. Take $x\mapsto (x^3,x^3+1)$. It's basically hopeless. Intermediate value theorem is essentially a topological result based on the fact that in $\mathbb{R}$ a connected set that contains a positive and a negative number is an interval containing zero. This clearly fails in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You are also misstating the quoted theorem.